# Formatting SSN using String.format

Tags: java, string.format

I am currently using a random genertor to generator numbers 9 digit numbers for me. I am currently trying to use String.format, in java, to print the random numbers like this XXX-XX-XXXX which is like a social security number. I simply cant do it and i not sure how to do. I am using modulo and it seems my padding are off or i am just completely wrong. The issues is that i have to use modulo. Any assistance pointing me to the right direction is much appreciated, thank you. I am trying to fix the ID.

```
public  String toString (){

        System.out.printf("%d\n",ID);

        return  String.format("First Name: %12s LastName %12s ID: %03d-%02d-%04d ", firstName, lastName,ID%1000,ID%10000, ID%000001000);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use decimal format class java

Comment: In your source code you must not have numbers that start with 0. Your number 00001000 is not 1000, but 512. Read something about _octal numbers_ to find out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing

```
return  String.format("First Name: %12s LastName %12s ID: %03d-%02d-%04d ", firstName, lastName,(int)ID/1000000,(int)(ID%1000000)/10000, ID%10000);
```

Comment: That Worked. Can you please explain why did you have to cast it with int?

Comment: I wasn't sure if ID was an integer, so I added it to be safe. If it was a double %0xd would need to be %0xf

Comment: Ok it was a int first, but you just added knowledge to my java programming. thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need two steps instead of one:

1. Divide the number by `10^X` to remove the last `X` digits. (`N / 10^X`)
2. Get the number modulo `10^Y` to take the last `Y` digits. (`N % 10^Y`)

**Modified Code**

```
public static int getDigits(int num, int remove, int take) {
    return (num / (int)Math.pow(10, remove)) % (int)Math.pow(10, take);
}

public String toString() {
    return  String.format("First Name: %12s LastName %12s ID: %03d-%02d-%04d ",
                          firstName, lastName,
                          getDigits(ID, 6, 3), getDigits(ID, 4, 2), getDigits(ID, 0, 4));
}
```

**Alternative Solution**

Convert the number to String and use [String.substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to cut the relevant pieces

```
public String toString() {
    String IdStr = String.valueOf(ID);
    return  String.format("First Name: %12s LastName %12s ID: %03d-%02d-%04d ",
                          firstName, lastName,
                          IdStr.substring(0, 3), IdStr.substring(3, 5), IdStr.substring(5, 9));
}
```